# Building polymorphic relations in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Answer have comments, comments have votes.
Answer have votes.

```
votes table:
id  user_id  vote  votable_id  votable_type
1     1       5     1          Comment
2     1       6     1          Post
...
```

**Post Model:**

```
 public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','post_id','id'); 
    }

   public function votes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Vote', 'votable');
    }
```

**Comment Model:**

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Vote', 'votable');
}

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post','post_id','id'); 
}
```

**Vote Model:**

```
 public function votable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

I am getting all the posts and their comments but not votes of posts and comments.

```
$posts=Post::all();
foreach($posts as $post)
{
     echo "<pre>"; print_r($post->post);    
     foreach($post->comments as $comment)
     {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($comment->comment_body);
        foreach($comment->votes as $vote)
        {
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($vote->vote);
        }               
     }

    foreach($post->votes as $vote)
    {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($vote->vote);
    }
}
```

`print_r($post->votes);` and `print_r($comment->votes);` doesnot show any relations with vote.

Comment: What does `dd($post->votes)` or `dd($comment->votes)` give you? Also, can you please post a screenshot of the Vote table?

Comment: @prateekkathal i don't get any votes relations.

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.2?

Comment: Since, you just edited your post and confirmed that you are using Laravel 5.2, I believe the `votable_type` should be **App\Comment** or **App\Post** and not just *Comment* or *Post*. Please confirm by changing the rows in some of the votable field and let me know if you are getting the expected output. :)

Comment: @prateekkathal entries are correct. Type column needs Model class name . https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: @jaysingkar If steve is not using **morphMap**, I am sure that is how the entries should be. Also, even though the documentation for 5.2 and 5.3 for Eloquent ORM is almost the same, I'd still ask you to link to the documentation of 5.2 and not confuse the user with 5.3.

Comment: @prateekkathal. oh. should be App\Comment or App\Post. thanks.

Comment: @prateekkathal sorry .. didn't think of **morphMap**.. :(

Comment: @Steve Please accept my answer :)

Comment: @jaysingkar It's okay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use **App\Comment** and **App\Post** instead of *Comment* or *Post* in the `votable` column.

Laravel 4.2 used to keep only the names of Models, but Laravel 5.2 stores them with the namespace now.

Let me know if there are any more doubts :)

-- Edit

As asked by @jaysingkar in the comments, I am adding the code for doing morphMap for this question.

Create your own service provider from the following command

```
php artisan make:provider RelationServiceProvider
```

Then, create put this after the namespace

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
```

and then add this to the `boot()` method

```
Relation::morphMap([
  'Posts' => App\Post::class,
  'Comments' => App\Comment::class,
]);
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: if possible. Could you please add **Morph Map** implementation also? Or if its ok I would edit your answer

Comment: @jaysingkar Done!